# Setting an Unreal Engine 5.1 Niagara Particle system to cast shadows from inside a Blueprint

Tags: particle-system, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I am using Unreal Engine 5.1, and I have a Blueprint that spawns a series of Niagara Particle systems.

I want these systems/particles to cast shadows, but the normal way of doing this (the 'Cast Shadows' setting in the details panel of the Niagara System instance) isn't available on systems created this way
[image: image of a Niagara system details panel, with 'Cast Shadow' setting visible]

How could I set this from within a Blueprint, or set it as 'true' by default in the System itself?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, you can plug the Niagara System reference into a "Set Cast Shadow" node and set that to true.

[image: Blueprint image of the "Set Cast Shadow" node in use]